# How to draw multi-series histogram from several pd.Series objects?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, histogram

I want to draw a multi-series histogram chart that looks like this:

[multi-series histogram chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRFOJ.png)

I'm trying to add this to an existing Jupyter notebook that already had code in place to establish a double chart:

```
    fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
```

The existing code uses the style where the plotting is done using methods on the data objects themselves. For example, here's some of the existing code that plots line charts in one of the existing subplots:

```
            ax = termstruct[i].T.plot.line(ax=ax, c=linecolor, 
                 dashes=dash, grid=True, linewidth=width, figsize=FIGURE_SIZE)
```

The main point I'm making here is that the way the plotting is achieved is to use the .plot.line method on the Pandas pd.Series (termstruct). This is not at all consistent with the examples and tutorials I was able to find online for drawing charts with pyplot, but it works and it establishes a framework I'm trying to work within.

So I started by taking the obvious step of adding a 3rd subplot for my histogram by changing the subplots call to plt from above:

```
    fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3,1)
```

My data are in four separate pd.Series objects, where each one represents a series that should map to one of the colors in the chart example at the top of this post. But when I try following the same general coding style of using methods on the data objects to do the plotting, I always seem to wind up with the X and Y axes opposite what I want, like this:

[what I wound up with!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUukH.png)

The code that generated the above chart was:

```
ax3 = NakedPNLperMo.plot.hist(ax=ax3,grid=True, figsize=FIGURE_SIZE)
ax3 = H9PNLperMo.plot.hist(ax=ax3, grid=True, figsize=FIGURE_SIZE)
ax3 = H12PNLperMo.plot.hist(ax=ax3, grid=True, figsize=FIGURE_SIZE)
ax3 = H15PNLperMo.plot.hist(ax=ax3, grid=True, figsize=FIGURE_SIZE)
```

NakedPNLperMo and the other 3 pd.Series objects are full of arcane financial symbols, but a simplified version of their contents (to make this clear) would be:

```
NakedPNLperMO = pd.Series(data=[1.2,3.4,5.6,7.8,-2.3,-4.6],
                          index=['Month 1','Month 2','Month 3','Month 4',
                                 'Month 5','Month 6'])
```

My intention/goal is that the data are plotted on the Y axis and the index values ('Month 1', etc.) are like columns across the x axis, but I can't seem to get that output no matter what I try.

Clearly the problem is the axes are swapped. But when I went looking for how to fix that, I couldn't find any examples online that follow this approach of drawing the chart using methods on the data objects. Everything I found in online tutorials was using a bunch of calls to plt to set up the charts. And more to the point, I couldn't see any way to follow the style in those examples and still draw the chart as a 3rd subplot alongside the 2 subplots already defined by this program.

My first (and foremost) question is what I SHOULD be trying next... Does it make sense to figure out how to change the parameters of [data-object].plot.xxx to get the axes the way I need them, or would it make more sense to follow the completely different style of making a series of calls to plt to design and draw the charts? The former would be consistent with what I have, but I can't find any online help for using that coding style. (Should I infer that it's a deprecated style of doing things?)

If the answer to the above is to take the approach of calling plt like the online examples all seem to show, how can I use the ax3 that ties this chart into the existing subplots? If the answer to the above is to stick with the approach of [data-object].plot.xxx, where can I find help on using that style? All the online examples I could find followed a different coding style.

And of course the most obvious question: How do I swap the axes so the chart looks right? :)

Thanks!

Comment: can you show example differents Series? You could use a DataFrame.plot()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code help you, I have created three series to show you how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#jupyter notebook only
%matplotlib inline
s1 = pd.Series(data=[1.2,3.4,5.6,7.8,-2.3,-4.6],
                          index=['Month 1','Month 2','Month 3','Month 4',
                                 'Month 5','Month 6'])
s2=pd.Series(data=[5,3.4,7.4,-5.1,-2.3,3],
                          index=['Month 1','Month 2','Month 3','Month 4',
                                 'Month 5','Month 6'])
s3=pd.Series(data=[5,2,-2.4,0,1,3],
                          index=['Month 1','Month 2','Month 3','Month 4',
                                 'Month 5','Month 6'])

df=pd.concat([s1,s2,s3],axis=1)
df.columns=['s1','s2','s3']
print(df)
ax=df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(10,10),fontsize=15)
#------------------------------------------------#
plt.xticks(rotation=-45)
#grid on
plt.grid()
# set y=0
ax.axhline(0, color='black', lw=1)
#change size of legend
ax.legend(fontsize=20)
#hiding upper and right axis layout
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
#changing the thickness
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)
ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(3)
```

Output:

```
          s1   s2   s3
Month 1  1.2  5.0  5.0
Month 2  3.4  3.4  2.0
Month 3  5.6  7.4 -2.4
Month 4  7.8 -5.1  0.0
Month 5 -2.3 -2.3  1.0
Month 6 -4.6  3.0  3.0
```

**Figure**

[image]

Comment: if you need ask me!

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks so much for the post. I was trying to use HIST instead of BAR charts. Anyway, pasting this code worked beautifully. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Your are welcome! Accept my answer  iy you don't  have any question